# Date.prototype.format is not a function

Tags: javascript, date

To format the date, I tried prototyping a method.

```
Date.prototype.formatYYYYMMDDHHMMSS = function() {
    return (this.getFullYear() + eval(this.getMonth() + 1) 
       + this.getDate() + this.getHours() + this.getMinutes() + this.getSeconds());
};

var upload = Date.now();
var uploadDate = upload.formatYYYYMMDDHHMMSS();
```

But following error is shown:

```
upload.formatYYYYMMDDHHMMSS is not a function
```

Comment: upload is not a Date object. It is a number

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use moment.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and not a `Date` object.

The correct way of using your approach would be:

```
var upload = new Date();
var uploadDate = upload.formatYYYYMMDDHHMMSS();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a date object `var upload = new Date();`

edit:
the ctor `Date()` default is now.